# How does ApiControllerAttribute affect unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core-2.1

In asp.net core 2.1 some new features have been introduced, specifically the [ApiControllerAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-2.1?view=aspnetcore-2.1#apicontroller-actionresult). In combination with the CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1 there are some changes in behaviour.

One of the changes is that the ModelState test can be omitted. Without ApiControllerAttribute I would need:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething([FromBody] SomeDto dto)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest();

    return Ok("Done");
}
```

And with ApiControllerAttribute:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething([FromBody] SomeDto dto)
{
    return Ok("Done");
}
```

Where an invalid dto would [automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#automatic-http-400-responses) result in a BadRequest.

But now for unit tests this doesn't work. If I want to test a controller, then in the previous situation the unit test would fail when an invalid dto was inserted. But in the current situation the ModelState isn't validated, meaning that the test will succeed.

So my question, do I have to use [Integration Tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-2.1?view=aspnetcore-2.1#integration-tests) now to test the controllers? Or is there another way to get the same behaviour based on the ApiControllerAttribute?

Comment: The `ApiControllerAttribute` is metadata that is only relevant at run time so that means you will have to use `TestServer` in an integration test and actually call the action under test for it to be part of the test.

Comment: So the new feature is in fact a breaking change? Because we can't use unit tests for controllers anymore.

Comment: It influences scenarios where you want to manually check model state and model state errors.

Comment: But I guess they are treating it as a cross cutting concern now.

Comment: It does not stop you from still including model state checks in your controller if using custom action filters or from directly returning from the action due to model state errors. Your first snippet is still allowable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ApiControllerAttribute` is metadata that is only relevant at run time so that means you will have to use `TestServer` in an integration test and actually call the action under test for it to be part of the test.

It influences scenarios where unit tests want to manually check model state and model state errors when testing controller actions in isolation.

It does not stop one from still including model state checks in a controller if using custom action filters or from directly returning from the action due to model state errors.

The features provided by the attribute just wont be available in isolated unit tests and tests would need to take that into consideration when it comes to expected behavior when being exercised.